# Change logon /disable Citrix XENAPP 5.0 farm wide or local

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, citrix, xenapp

I want to disable logons before I do maintenance on a single server in the farm.
If i run `change logon /disable` will that disable logons on that server or will that disable logons on the entire farm?
The docs http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX564871 don't really specify, though there is a link to another article on the bottom that has a VB script for presentation server 4, but I'm on XENAPP 5.0.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change logon /disable will disable logons only for the server that you run the command on.

Comment: Just wanted to check before running it.  I would have a lot of questions to answer if no one could log in the next morning :)  Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help...